# Can't install macOS Ventura from recovery: com.apple.BuildInfo.preflight.error error 10

Tags: macos, disk-utility, install, recovery

I am trying to install macOS Ventura 13.5 using internet recovery, meaning a version of the OS is downloaded and then installed.

I partitioned the disk using Disk Utility and formatted using a `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` file system. I named the partition "Macintosh HD"

I then quit Disk Utility and went to reinstall macOS.

When I clicked the "Macintosh HD" disk in the installer a small popover appeared stating:

```
The operation could not be completed (com.apple.BuildInfo.preflight.error error 10.)
```

Comment: I think it would be useful to include the version of macOS you are installing.

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks, added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally worked for me was going back to Disk Utility and then reformatting the disk using `APFS` instead!

After reformatting using `APFS` instead of `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` the recovery installer was happy to accept the "Macintosh HD" disk as an install target!